# Stack overflow inside Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug

I was browsing Stack Overflow and encountered an ad for https://aviation.stackexchange.com/. I don't remember in particular what the ad was about, but after clicking on the ad, it didn't redirect to the site, but it opened Stack Overflow in place of the ad. You can see it on the right-hand side below the hot meta posts.

[image]

I could even browse that little window. Here I've clicked on `Ask Question`.

[image]

The browser is Firefox v68.0 64-bit.

Comment: That is the ultimate responsiveness test. Now try to navigate to the same ad and click on that ad ...

Comment: S T A C K C E P T I O N

Comment: Too many stacks within a stack can lead to a... Wait for it... Heap Overflow! Wait, that's not right ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: BWAAAAAAAAAP